Lattice in a simply connected nilpotent Lie group
Given a connected and simply connected nilpotent Lie group $N$ with a left invariant metric, we assume that there is a lattice $\Gamma$ of $G$. Let $B_1(e)$ be the $1$-ball at the identity element in $N$. My question is: can we find a normal subgroup $\Gamma'$ of $\Gamma$, such that $\Gamma' \cap B_1(e)= \{e \}$?
This is obviously true if $N$ is abelian, since we can multiply large $k$ to each generator of $\Gamma$ to get generators of $\Gamma'$. I don't know how to do for a general simply connected nilpotent lie group.

Yes, just use that $\Gamma$ is residually finite, a classical result of Malcev. No need to introduce a metric to formulate the question. Just replace $B_1(e)$ with an arbitrary compact set.
